# Scrapy Request callbacks not firing

Tags: python, python-2.7, callback, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy 0.24 to scrape data from a website. However, I am unable to make any requests from my callback method `parse_summary`.

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tfrrs"
    allowed_domains = ["example.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.org/results_search.html?page=0&sport=track&title=1&go=1',
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TfrrsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = ['http://www.example.org/results_search.html?page=0&sport=track'&title=1&go=1',]
            pass

    # works without issue
    def parse(self, response):
        races = response.xpath("//table[@width='100%']").xpath(".//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://www.tfrrs.org/results/')]/@href").extract()
        callback = self.parse_trackfieldsummary
        for race in races:
            yield scrapy.Request(race, callback=self.parse_summary)
        pass

    # works without issue
    def parse_summary(self, response):
        baseurl = 'http://www.example.org/results/'
        results = response.xpath("//div[@class='data']").xpath('.//a[@style="margin-left: 20px;"]/@href').extract()
        for result in results:
            print(baseurl+result)  # shows that url is correct everytime
            yield scrapy.Request(baseurl+result, callback=self.parse_compiled)

    # is never fired or shown in terminal
    def parse_compiled(self, response): 
        print('test')
        results = response.xpath("//table[@style='width: 935px;']")
        print(results)
```

When I intentially make the request in `parse_summary` fail (due to domain errors, etc), I am able to see the error in the prompt, but when I use the correct url, its as if I am not even calling it. I have also tested the urls being requested in `parse_summary` in the `parse` method, where they work as expected. What could be causing them to not be fired in the `parse_summary` method but successfully in the `parse method`?  Thank you for your help in advance.

### Edit

After making some changes to my `Spider`, I still have the same result. However, it works if I use an entirely new project. So I am guessing it has to do with my project settings.

Here are my project settings (where `raceretrieval` is the name of my project):

```
BOT_NAME = 'raceretrieval'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY= 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 100
SPIDER_MODULES = ['raceretrieval.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'raceretrieval.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
        'raceretrieval.pipelines.RaceValidationPipeline':1,
        'raceretrieval.pipelines.RaceDistanceValidationPipeline':2,
#        'raceretrieval.pipelines.RaceUploadPipeline':9999
    }
```

If I comment out **both** `DOWNLOAD_DELAY= 1` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 100`, the spider works as expected.  Why could this be? I don't understand how they would effect this.

Comment: Does adding `dont_filter=True` in Reuques work? btw, absolute url: `urlparse.urljoin(response.url, result)` may be a little bit better.

Comment: The code you share needs some improvements. There are few typos, you work on 2 different urls(example.org tfrrs.org) and methods are missing(parse_trackfieldsummary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I corrected few typos and set correctly the allowed domains and parse_summary seems to work fine.
Urls are extracted and parse_compile results are correctly shown in the terminal.

Output are lines as the following:

```
2014-12-29 12:19:05+0100 [example] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
http://www.tfrrs.org/results/36288_f.html> (referer:
http://www.tfrrs.org/results/36288.html) <200
http://www.tfrrs.org/results/36288_f.html> 
[<Selector xpath="//table[@style='width: 935px;']" data=u'<table width="0" border="0" cellspacing='>, <Selector xpath="//table[@style='width: 935px;']" data=u'<table width="0" border="0" cellspacing='> .....
```

Here it is the corrected code:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["tfrrs.org"]
    start_urls = (
    'http://www.tfrrs.org/results_search.html?page=0&sport=track&title=1&go=1',
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.start_urls = ['http://www.tfrrs.org/results_search.html?page=0&sport=track&title=1&go=1',]


# works without issue
def parse(self, response):
    races = response.xpath("//table[@width='100%']").xpath(".//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://www.tfrrs.org/results/')]/@href").extract()
    #callback = self.parse_trackfieldsummary
    for race in races:
        yield scrapy.Request(race, callback=self.parse_summary)
    pass

# works without issue
def parse_summary(self, response):
    baseurl = 'http://www.tfrrs.org/results/'
    results = response.xpath("//div[@class='data']").xpath('.//a[@style="margin-left: 20px;"]/@href').extract()
    for result in results:
        #print(baseurl+result)  # shows that url is correct everytime
        yield scrapy.Request(baseurl+result, callback=self.parse_compiled)

# is never fired or shown in terminal
def parse_compiled(self, response): 
    print(response)
    results = response.xpath("//table[@style='width: 935px;']")
    print(results)
```

Comment: I just tried making the correction using snippets from your corrected version. I could not get it to work, so I tried replacing it entirely with your corrected version (failed as well). So I created an entirely new project and used your code. Which worked exactly as planned. I am adding my `settings`, maybe it is an error with my settings?

Comment: I used your download_delay and concurrent_request configuration and it keeps working fine. My scrapy version is 0.24.4. What about the item pipelines ?

Comment: I do not think the pipelines are ever executed, due to lack of of feedback in the terminal. I added some lines to print to the terminal in the pipelines and they are not printing to it. Its possible that this is just something specific to my installation, since you are not having these issues.

Comment: @aberna I was struggling on this, in my case it was `allowed_domains`.

Answer (score -3):

These should fix the issue you were having

```
find / -type d -name "__pycache__" -delete 2>/dev/null

find / -name '*.pyc' -delete

find / -name '*.egg'
```

**Edit:**

if that doesn't solve it then the issue may actually be that the download delay is literally backlogging the last request which will be yielded eventually, just in a very long time ^^